# maintainParty transaction IBM MDM and the symbol '&' in xml

Tags: informatica, master-data-management, ibm-infosphere

ETL-Informatica team prepares an XML (maintainParty transaction) to be consumed by IBM-MDM .

In general an XML cannot have the symbol '&' and it has to be replaced by **`&amp;`**

Instead of repacing the symbol '&' by the entity `&amp;` , is there any other way that automatically Informatica or MDM can parse the values and make is as proper xml by converting all & into `&amp;`

The reason I ask is, in production env , ETL team sends with '&' symbol and mdm consumes it properly.

However, in test servers it throws the error below. hence I am trying to understand if there is any configuration in MDM or Informatica where it will convert all & symbol to proper entities.

Request:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
..
<TCRMTx>
        <TCRMTxType>maintainParty</TCRMTxType>
..
..
..
<TCRMAdminContEquivBObj>
                    <AdminPartyId>000000F:PI:::Chandru & Mohan HEADRI:</AdminPartyId>
                    <AdminSystemType>1000000</AdminSystemType>
                </TCRMAdminContEquivBObj>

..
..
```

Response Error:

```
<TxResponse>
        <RequestType>maintainParty</RequestType>
        <TxResult>
            <ResultCode>FATAL</ResultCode>
            <DWLError>
                <ComponentType>106</ComponentType>
                <ErrorMessage>Parser DWLTransaction failed. The format of the message is not correct or an application error occurred.</ErrorMessage>
                <ErrorType>READERR</ErrorType>
                <LanguageCode>100</LanguageCode>
                <ReasonCode>4928</ReasonCode>
                <Severity>0</Severity>
                <Throwable>com.dwl.base.requestHandler.exception.RequestParserException: [Exception_myErrorHandler_SAXParseError:] The parsing of the XML failed at the following position. XML = org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the &apos;&amp;&apos; in the entity reference.; line number = 53; column number = 44</Throwable>
            </DWLError>
        </TxResult>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are using an XML Generator transformation in Informatica to create the XML to MDM it should automatically convert `&` to `&amp;`.

Maybe they are overwriting this property? https://kb.informatica.com/solution/14/Pages/109542.aspx